# Can the geographic co-ordinate system of a shapefile be identified using Cartopy?

Tags: python, shapefile, cartopy

I have a shapefile that I have downloaded onto my local hard drive. I can use Cartopy to read the shapefile and plot a map using Matplotlib as follows:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import cartopy.io.shapereader as shpreader
reader = shpreader.Reader('/path_to_shapefile/myShapeFile.shp')
ax = plt.axes(projection=ccrs.OSGB())
ax.add_geometries(reader.geometries(),ccrs.OSGB(),edgecolor = 'k',facecolor = 'none')
plt.show()
```

However, I would like to be able to identify the geographic co-ordinate system of the shapefile (e.g. WGS84 or OSGB) so that I can make sure that it matches the co-ordinate values of some points that I want to plot on the same map. Having read the shapefile, I assume that Cartopy can display the coordinate system used but I can't find out how to do so. Can Cartopy do this or do I need to use a different package?

Answer (score 1):

Cartopy is using [pyshp](https://github.com/GeospatialPython/pyshp) under the hood to read the shapefile. As far as I can tell, that library does not provide the information you are looking for. (CartoPy does not expose this information about PyShp anyway.)

Your best bet may be to look at [Fiona](https://toblerity.org/fiona/manual.html), which are nice Python bindings for GDAL. You could use this to open the shapefile manually and inspect--I *assume* this library will provide the information you're looking for, if anything in the Python space does.

Comment: Thanks very much for the info. I had continued to look for a solution but couldn't find an answer; it's good to have my suspicions confirmed. I ended up using GeoPandas which reads shapefiles and gives the CRS very easily.